# convert Bash script code, for code bat file windows

Tags: linux, windows, bash, batch-file

I wrote this bash script for Linux and I want someone to convert this script to bat (file) for windows.

```
#!/bin/bash

if curl -s --head http://google.com/ | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null
then 
    yes | cp -i /etc/hosts_bk /etc/hosts
else 
    echo "127.0.0.1 example.com" > /etc/hosts
    echo "127.0.0.1 www.example.com" >> /etc/hosts
fi
```

Comment: Look that [dos-bash-table-conversion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html). That is a good start.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what gave you the impression that this is a code-writing service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@echo off

curl -s --head http://google.com/ | findstr /c:"200 OK" >nul 2>&1

if errorlevel 1 (
    :: "200 OK" not found
    echo yes | copy /-Y %windir%\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts_bk %windir%\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
) else (
    :: "200 OK" found
    echo "127.0.0.1 example.com"> %windir%\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
    echo "127.0.0.1 www.example.com">> %windir%\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
)
exit /b 0
```

Comment: We're answering off-topic questions now? _Really?_ I get that 90% of the code is the same, but it's for that exact reason that it's obvious that he did literally no research and the question shouldn't have been answered. -1

Comment: thank you very much,
but i reversed 
when 200 found , get backup hosts, 
and when not found , write 127.0.0.1 example.com on hosts file ,
thanks again